# Need to create 410 status code in Wordpress site for all pages in /forums/ folder

Tags: http-status-code-410

I was asked by a friend to fix a wordpress website with a bb press forum that was over-run by spammers. The wordpress site was okay, but the bb forum had over 1,500 urls of spammed entries in the space of about 3 months. The site is hosted by Godaddy and the person who was managing it was instructed by them to delete all content. They did this and now the webmaster tools is showing 1,500 404 errors. I have since deleted and reinstalled plugins on site and locked down wordpress to not allow subscribers or comments. Spam visits have diminished tremendously. But the damage is still there.

I have read extensively about creating 410 Gone command for search engines on those now deleted spammed posts. No where can I find sample code and instructions on where to insert the code appropriately. I have access to ftp and know how to open `.htaccess` in text edit. I also know where to find php files and how to get access to them. But I only know enough about php to get myself into a lot of trouble.

I found a site that offers `.htaccess` code sample. So I have attempted to plug in my data and am just looking for a 'spot check' from someone who knows the code.

I am keeping everything in the domain as is but need to redirect the subfolder http://www.mydomain.com/forums/ and everything in it to display a 410, meaning that all content is permanently gone inside that /forums/ folder and search engine no longer should look for it.

Here is the sample `.htaccess` file code I found:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.ourdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
#
# Folder that exists no more
RewriteRule ^forums/discontinued\.html$ - [G]
#
Redirect 301 /folder/index.html http://www.ourdomain.com/forums/
#
# File that exists no more
Redirect gone [b]/f[/b]ilea.html
```

Is this the proper code to place inside the .htaccess file on my wordpress site to eliminate searches on the now deleted `/forums/` folder and all content that was ever posted in it?

I appreciate all help on this.

Also, where can I get a tutorial on how to write `.htaccess` code online, for future reference.

Thank you very much for the help. I am grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /forums/(.*)
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/forums/$1 [R=410,L]
```

That will catch anything that starts with http://www.example.com/forums and redirect it to a 410.

Also note, if you are modifying an existing .htaccess, it likely already has the `RewriteEngine On` line somewhere near the top (usually the first non-comment line), so you don't need to have it twice. Just the RewriteRule added somewhere should work. If there are lots of other RewriteRules, you should probably put it near the top. If there are just a few default lines from Wordpress, below those should suffice.

Comment: That won't catch at all what you said. With your rule, you're redirecting **everything** to *forums* directory (with **gone** header)

Comment: You are correct. Sorry, I got distracted while writing that. I've correct it.

Comment: Thanks Justin lurman and samanime. I have entered the code in the website .htaccess file (with the edit). I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

This could also be done by using the following, single rule:

`RewriteRule ^/forums(/.*)?$  - [G,NC]`

This will 410 all the following URLs:

```
http://www.example.com/forums
http://www.example.com/forums/
http://www.example.com/forums/my-forum-post-1
http://www.example.com/forums/my-forum-post-2/
```

The `[G]` flag denotes the `410 Gone` status, the `[NC]` flag makes the URLs case-insensitive, and the `[L]` isn't needed since it's implied with the `[G]` flag.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing the 410 status code can also be done via PHP. Here is a snippet to help you get started:

```
add_action( 'parse_query', 'child_parse_query' );
function child_parse_query( $obj ) {
  if ( $obj .... ) {  // Insert your query conditions here
    /* Add your code here */
    $obj->set_404(); // Set the 404 property. Otherwise it will return a 200 ok status code.
    status_header( 410 ); // Set the Status Header
    nocache_headers();
    add_filter( 'template_include', 'return_410_template_callback' ); // If you want to show a custom 410 template instead of the 404 template
  }
}
```